# Is it impossible to get rid of Google ReCaptch Error?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

In Google ReCaptch Error, the following errors occur with a probability of about 1%.

- timeout-or-duplicate
- browser-error
- invalid-input-response

Is it impossible to reduce these error rates to 0?

It's happening in a web application I'm publishing. There are hundreds of thousands of accesses per month, and there are accesses from various devices and browsers.